# Flutter get all map entries where map value matches condition

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to find all elements in a Map where a condition is met.

My widget receives `final Map<String, Item> itemMap;` from a Parent Widget

I have a function that gets called when a `Dropdown` element is selected

```
  handleTypeSelect(String? selectedType) {
    var newList = widget.itemMap.entries
        .where((element) => element.value.type == selectedType)
        .toList();

    var foo = Map<String, Item>.fromIterable(newList);
    var bar = Map<String, Item>.fromEntries(newList);
    print('newlist ${bar}');
   
  }
```

All I need is to create a new `Map` with the same structure `Map<String, Item>` that only contains the map entries where `Item.type` matched the `type` selected from the dropdown. I tried several things but always ended up with different errors like: `Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'MapEntry<String, Item>'` or some Map of entries that I am unable to access.

Item Model is probably not relevant but just in case it helps.

```
  final String name;
  final String id;
  final String type;
  final int circulation;
  final String description;
  final String imageLink;
  final int marketValue;
```

Comment: rather than `element.value.type == selectedType`, you should use a true Type, and `element.value is Type`.  See Iterable.whereType, or just use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Map<int, bool> example = {1: true, 2: false};
var trueEntries = example.entries.where((MapEntry e) => e.value);
print(Map.fromEntries(trueEntries));
```

Which yields `{1: true}`.

In your code it would probably be something like this:

```
  handleTypeSelect(String? selectedType) {
    var filteredEntries = widget.itemMap.entries
        .where((MapEntry e) => e.value.type == selectedType);
    var bar = Map.fromEntries(newList);   
  }
```